# How would I create rectangle collisions in processing?

Tags: collision-detection, processing, collision

I am working on a platformer and I need some very basic collisions that I can't seem to come up with myself. It always seems to find a way to glitch through and fly off the screen, or get stuck to the ceiling.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    if (player.y-8+player.height>loc.y && player.y<loc.y+height-8) {
      if (player.x+player.width>loc.x && player.x<loc.x+8) {
        player.xvelocity=0;
        player.x = loc.x-player.width-1;
      }
      if (player.x+8>loc.x && player.x<loc.x+width) {
        player.xvelocity=0;
        player.x = loc.x+dim+1;
      }
    }



    if (player.x+player.width>loc.x && player.x<loc.x+width) {
      if (player.y+player.height>loc.y && player.y<loc.y+8) {
        player.yvelocity=0; 
        player.y = loc.y-player.height;
        ground = true;
      }
      if (player.y+8>loc.y && player.y<loc.y+height) {
        player.yvelocity=0; 
        player.y = loc.y+dim;
      }
    }
```

The width of the player is 15 and the height is 25, the width of the square is 16 and the height is 16.

I have tried looking elsewhere on the internet for an answer to this but all I get is collision detection (checking if two objects are intersecting) which I already know how to do. Thanks.

Also I am working on the collisions from the square/rectangle.

Comment: Fly through glitches can happen if the speed of the moving object is too high. If in one update the object moves all the way through a collider then you won't detect the collision. There are different methods to prevent this from happening, but this is not basic collision anymore. Are you dealing with high movement speed or not?

Comment: Not particularly high speeds, no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found a solution to the problem. For people also having difficulty with collision detection and handling, check out this http://www.hobbygamedev.com/adv/2d-platformer-advanced-collision-detection/ it helped me.